# Ignoring empty elements matched by {} in recursive rule

Tags: grako

I would like to describe a nestable condition. Here is what I'm working with :

```
expr = ( /[_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/ ) ;

condop = ( "AND" | "OR" ) ;
condition = expr { condop condition } ;

start = condition ;
```

I can generate an AST with lines like :

```
foo AND bar
```

Here the AST :

```
[
  "foo", 
  [
    [
      "AND", 
      [
        "bar", 
        []
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

But there is an empty list after "bar", because I guess the last time the condition rule is matched, "condop condition" worth an empty string. According to the docs https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grako/3.16.0, {} generates an empty list.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is not Grako-specific. You're using both recursion and closures on the same rule.

There are (more than) two ways to describe those expressions:

```
condition = expr { condop expr } ;
```

or

```
condition = expr [ condop condition ] ;
```

or

```
condition = expr condop condition | expr;
```

which is equivalent to the previous one.

Left recursion doesn't work in all cases with Grako, so use it at your own risk. The equivalent would be:

```
condition = condition condop condition | expr;
```